# Spring Webflux Wait for all Flux.fromIterable before returning response

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a reactive service and it works fine

```
public Mono<GetCasesListResponse> getCasesList(@RequestBody GetCasesListRequest request) {
        return casesService.getCasesList(mapToGetCasesListServiceRequest(request))
                .map(GetCasesListMapper::mapGetCasesListResponse)
                .onErrorResume(exceptionHandler::fallbackMethod);
}
```

casesService

```
public Mono<GetCasesListServiceResponse> getCasesList(GetCasesListServiceRequest request) {
        return webClient.post()
                .uri("/getCasesList")
                .bodyValue(request)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(GetCasesListResponse.class);
}
```

But now I have the next task. For each element from the map obtain data from another service in parallel and also from list. And add this data to each element of the array in GetCasesListResponse.
I decided to use Flux.fromIterable

first add flatMap

```
public Mono<GetCasesListResponse> getCasesList(@RequestBody GetCasesListRequest request) {
        return casesService.getCasesList(mapToGetCasesListServiceRequest(request))
                .map(GetCasesListMapper::mapGetCasesListResponse)
                .flatMap(this::getMoreComments)
                .onErrorResume(exceptionHandler::fallbackMethod);
}
```

```
private Mono<GetCasesListResponse> getMoreComments(GetCasesListResponse casesListResponse) {
        collectExtIds(casesListResponse).forEach((id, extIdList) -> fromIterable(extIdList).parallel()
                .flatMap(extId -> stpService.getMoreComments(mapToGetMoreCommentsRequest(extId)))
                .subscribe(moreCommentsResponse -> addMoreCommentsToGetCasesListResponse(casesListResponse, id, moreCommentsResponse)));

        return Mono.just(casesListResponse);
}
```

getMoreComments

```
public Mono<GetCommentResponse> getMoreComments(GetCommentRequest request) {
        return webClient.post()
                .uri("/getCaseComments")
                .bodyValue(request)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(GetCommentResponse.class)
}
```

But I have a problem with getMoreComments because this method returns Mono.just(casesListResponse) before the fromIterable complete. And I get casesListResponse without any additional data. How can I wait to receive data from fromIterable for each element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems:

- You should not use `subscribe`, and it's the rule of a thump that you should avoid using unless you know why exactly you need it and cannot rely on other ways
- Usually, when you want to return a value *after* some other reactive flow,  you use `then(result)`
- But in this case you actually return the same object, with changed properties. Which, in general, is not okay.
- A good code would accumulate all the comments into a list (using a `reduce`) and set it to the result only on the last step. But if you're sure that your object is thread-safe you can do like in your code (and it shown in my example)
- Btw, using a `parallel` doesn't do anything in your case. It's useful only for a high-CPU `map` and requires `runOn` configuration. Standard `flatMap` is already parallel.

It should be something like this:

```
Mono<GetCasesListResponse> getMoreComments(
     GetCasesListResponse casesListResponse
) {
    Flux.fromIterable(collectExtIds(casesListResponse))
        .flatMap( (id, extIdList) -> 
            Flux.fromIterable(extIdList)
                .flatMap(extId ->        
                    stpService.getMoreComments(
                        mapToGetMoreCommentsRequest(extId)
                    )
                )
                .reduce(casesListResponse, (accum, moreComments) ->
                     addMoreCommentsToGetCasesListResponse(
                        accum, id, moreComments)
                    )
                )
        )
        .last()
}
```

I used `last` here only because all `flatMap` return the same instance of the `casesListResponse` object. But if you can do a `then(casesListResponse)` instead. Also I would suggest to rewrite the `GetCasesListResponse` in a way it can accept the list of all the comments so the reduce wouldn't operate a shared instance